# No signin id passed, IdentityServer3, using OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions

Tags: middleware, identityserver3, quickbooks-online, katana

I'm trying to implement Quickbooks SSO provider with Katana middleware.

```
  app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions...
   ...
    SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,//"idsrv.external"
    ...
```

As a response I get callback to IS3: http://localhost:44333/callback?state=...

..and it says about error: *"No signin id passed"*

Do I need to handle it in OpenIdConnectAuthentication.Notifications , or maybe override something in OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler

Thank you in advance.-)

Answer (score 2):

some code:

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions

```
        {
            ClientId = IntuitClientId,
            Authority = "Quickbooks",
            MetadataAddress = "https://developer.intuit.com/.well-known/openid_sandbox_configuration/",
            RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44333/callback",
            CallbackPath = new PathString("/callback"),
            ClientSecret = IntuitClientSecret,
            ResponseType = "code",//code only for Intuit
            Scope = "com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting",
```

Answer (score 0):

I've connected IdentityServer3 sources to debug, it cannot take "signin" from middleware, here:

```
public static async Task<string> GetSignInIdFromExternalProvider(...
{
    ...
    var result = await context.GetAuthenticationFrom(Constants.ExternalAuthenticationType);
   ...
 result.Properties.Dictionary.TryGetValue(Constants.Authentication.SigninId, out val))
       ...
}
```

and

```
public static async Task<Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticateResult> GetAuthenticationFrom(this IOwinContext context, string authenticationType)
{
    ...
        return await context.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync(authenticationType);
}
```

Comment: a chat about an issue from Katana github: github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/142